# Objective-C differentiate between own classes and Apple/Language classes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to use introspection to modify an object. However, I need a way of knowing if I created that object class, or if it is something in Foundation, etc...

Is there a property I can access (even in objcruntime.h) to see this?

Comment: There's `class_getImageName()`. You could compare its return value to the name of known frameworks/libraries by Apple (e. g. `Foundation`, `libSystem.dylib`, etc), .

Comment: Ok thanks. I just want to identify my own objects. Is there a notApple obj method? I don't want to build an exhaustive library of apple objects.

Comment: I don't know of one.

Comment: Take a step back and explain more of what you're trying to accomplish and why.  There may be a better way to do what you're trying to do.